# Clicking on uitableview button after putting viewcontroller on top

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

viewcontroller A has a uitableview with buttons on each row, viewcontroller B is added to the left of viewcontroller A when any button is pressed. I adjusted the frames so that they don't overlap. But once i add viewcontroller B i can no longer click on the buttons on viewcontroller A.Any suggestions?

Thank You

Comment: figured it out. had to use [self.view.superview addSubview: [viewcontrollerB view]]; instead of [self.view addSubview: [viewcontrollerB view]];

Comment: If you found the answer, make sure you post it as an answer and then check it off as the correct one. Otherwise this post will look like a never ending story... Close it off! P.S. for your next post, make sure that you add the code that is relevant.